# ViewGroup addview() is invalid in Android 7.0

Tags: view

customlayout through addview() is invalid in Android 7.0 ,the layout is disappear.
below 7.0 is succuss. but  I  log this layout width and height are 0 in Android 5.0、6.0、7.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You should set LayoutParams also.
For example:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("this view is added dynamically");
mainLayout.addView(text);
```

Comment: I show my code in another comment,Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I set LayoutPrams :

```
public class Card extends FrameLayout {
...

    private void initial() {
        label = new TextView(getContext());
        label.setTextSize(32);
        label.setBackgroundColor(0x33ff0033);
        label.setTextColor(0x330D0D0D);
        label.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
        addView(label, lp);
        setNum(0);
    }
...
}
```

and  I  set :

```
public  NumLayout extends GridLayout{
...
private void addCard(int cardWidth, int cardHeight) {
        Card card;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < NUMBER; y++) {
                card = new Card(getContext());
                card.setNum(number[sum]-1);
                addView(card, cardWidth, cardHeight);
                point[x][y] = card;
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```